# How to fix: b = re.search('\(.*).\d+\.tld', a)

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the code:

```
a = '000.222.tld'
b = re.search('(.*).\d+\.tld', a)
```

would like to see it print

000

so far..

```
  print b.group(0)
```

gives me this:

```
  000.222.tld

   print b.group(1)
```

gives me this:

```
000.2
```

Comment: The regex in your code isn't even valid; the `\(` is escaped, so the (non-escaped) `)` doesn't match anything. I think you were trying to write a capturing group, in which case you don't want to escape either parenthesis. Also, you should always use raw string literals with regexps—do you know the list of Python backslash escapes so well that you can say for sure whether `'\d'` means anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a a few problems with your expression:

```
b = re.match('\(.*)\.\d+\.com', a)
```

First, that `\(` means that you're escaping the `(`—it will only match a literal `(` character in the search string. You're not trying to match any parentheses, you're trying to create a capturing group, so don't escape the parens. (Also, you're *not* escaping the matching `)`, so you'd get an error about mismatched parens trying to use this…)

Second, you're trying to match `.com`, but your sample input ends in `.tld`. Those obviously aren't going to match. Presumably you wanted to match any string of letters, or some other rule?

Finally, you're not using a raw string literal, or escaping your backslashes. Sometimes you get away with this, but do you know the Python backslash-escape rules by heart so well that you can be sure that `\d` or `\.` doesn't mean anything? Do you expect anyone who reads your code to also know?

If you fix all of those problems, your regex works:

```
>>> a = '1.2.tld'
>>> b = re.match(r'(.*)\.\d+\.[A-Za-z]+', a)
>>> b.group(1)
'1'
```

---

Now that you've completely changed both the expression and the input, you have completely *different* problems:

```
b = re.search('(.*).\d+\.tld', a)
```

The main problem here, besides again not using a raw string literal, is that you didn't escape the first `.`, so you're searching for *any character* there. Since regular expressions are greedy by default, the first `.*` will capture as much as it can while still leaving room for any character, 1 or more digits, and `.tld`, so it will match `000.2`. But if you escape the `.`, it will capture as much as it can while still leaving room for a literal `.`, 1 or more digits, and `.tld`, which is exactly what you want.

```
>>> a = '000.222.tld'
>>> b = re.search(r'(.*)\.\d+\.tld', a)
>>> b.group(1)
'000'
```

---

Meanwhile, there are some great regular expression debuggers, both downloadable and online. I don't want to recommend one in particular, but Debuggex makes it easy to create a sharable link to a particular test, so [here](https://www.debuggex.com/r/QxR-gSVoT_9hEZhW) is your first one, and [here](https://www.debuggex.com/r/oO33_VXMd7DV_M-X) is your second. Check out the examples and see how much easier it is to find the problems with your pattern that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without regex:

```
b = a.split('.', 1)[0]
```

Comment: +1. And probably _should_, too. The main reason to use regex is that in many cases it lets you express things that would be so clunky or verbose as to be hard to read and maintain if written with string methods. If you can't figure out how to write and debug a regex, and multiple attempts aren't getting you any closer to understanding, then even if you get the result, odds are it's not going to be more readable to you (and your intended readers) than the string methods. And in this case, the clunkiness is minimal (even if you add in validating that `[1]` was an int and `[2]` was `'tld'`).